# Finding Similar Artists with the Amazon Product API

Tags: amazon-product-api

I'm relatively new to the Amazon Product API and I am attempting to pull back similar artists to the artist on an item I am providing for the Similarity Lookup.

For instance using the following parameters:

- ItemId='B00136JMX6'
- Operation='SimilarityLookup'
- ResponseGroup='ItemAttributes,Images'
- Availability='Available'
- SearchIndex='MP3Downloads'

I receive only other songs by Johnny Cash.

Is there a way to find other artists similar to Mr. Cash?

Comment: I looked around a bit more and think I might need to pull this info from Last.FM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've spent a lot of time working with both APIs and yes it is easy to get five similar artists from Last.fm then you could search based on those artists.  You could perhaps use MusicBrainz...  They also make use of ASIN numbers in their database.  I don't make use of MusicBrainz much but it is another option I looked at.

Good luck!

[My code in PHP for working with these APIs](http://www.muschamp.ca/Muskie/webMashups.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorry it took me so long to respond.

Comment: No worries, it is definitely doable. I don't think the Amazon Product Advertising API is a big priority for Amazon these days. It still works, but making it easier to work with isn't on the agenda. Last.fm users provide similar artists and then you could search Amazon for them no troubles with my code.